# unexpected elements in imported Compressed data into Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I am trying to load a compressed TXT file into Hive. The operation ends without any error, however in the constructed table there are some unexpected characters in the beginning. Why this happend?
More info about compressed data storage in Hive: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/CompressedStorage

```
# cat test.txt
        tab1    tab2    tab3
        tab4    tab5    tab6
        tab7    tab8    tab9

# tar -cvzf test.gz test.txt
test.txt

# cat hiveQuery.hql
CREATE TABLE raw (col1 STRING,col2 STRING,col3 STRING)
   ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
;
LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH '/test.gz' INTO TABLE raw;

#  hive -f hiveQuery.hql
WARNING: Use "yarn jar" to launch YARN applications.

Logging initialized using configuration in file:/etc/hive/2.4.0.0-169/0/hive-log4j.properties
OK
Time taken: 6.936 seconds
Loading data to table default.raw
Table default.raw stats: [numFiles=1, totalSize=145]
OK

# hive -e "select * from raw"
WARNING: Use "yarn jar" to launch YARN applications.

Logging initialized using configuration in file:/etc/hive/2.4.0.0-169/0/hive-log4j.properties
OK
test.txt                                                                  0000644 0000000 0000000 00000000055 13120243734 011273  0                 ustar   root                            root                              tab1    tab2    tab3
tab4    tab5    tab6
tab7    tab8    tab9
                                                                          NULL    NULL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tar` format contains additional header information.
Compress your file using `gzip` and see that it works fine.